# Pandas to HDF5?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

How do I convert a big table in Pandas/Numpy to h5 format with the same structure? I used the next code, but received .h5 version with messy data

```
data.to_hdf('data.h5',format = 'table', key='data')
```

I attached the image with my data[image]
Or which data type can you recommend ?
I received the next structure
[image]

Comment: Setting `format = 'table'` outputs a table structure (the most intuitive format). Please describe what you mean by "messy data".

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I attached image with format that I received in my question.

Comment: I forgot, you also need `data_columns=True` to write each dataframe as a separate file (column) in the table. See simple example below with 3 dataframes and 10 rows from your data above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `format='table'` writes the data as a PyTables Table. When you do this all the data will be in the 'table' dataset in group defined by `key=`. However, data of common data types will be grouped together in 1 'values_block_#' column/field (all ints, all floats, etc). To write them separately, you also need `data_columns=True`. That defines the columns to be created as indexed data columns (set to `True` to use all columns).
Example below demonstrate the differences from each option. It creates 3 different files using data from your example. If you still don't like the format with `data_columns=True`, you can use h5py or tables (PyTables) package to create the HDF5 schema and write the data as you like.

1. file_1.h5 - uses default format ('fixed')
2. file_2.h5 - uses 'table' format (only)
3. file_3.h5 - uses 'table' format with `data_columns=True`

Code below:

```
id = [f'subj8_series8_{i}' for i in range(5) ] + \
     [f'subj8_series8_12409{i}' for i in range(5) ] 
Fp1 = [ 12, 157, 34, -98, 28,
       -160, -30, 64, 134, 159 ]
Fp2 = [ 60, 181, 111, 25, 120,
        192, 261, 322, 383, 407 ]

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'Fp1': Fp1, 'Fp2': Fp2})

df.to_hdf('file_1.h5', key='data') 
df.to_hdf('file_2.h5', key='data', format='table') 
df.to_hdf('file_3.h5', key='data', format='table', data_columns=True)
```