# How to read HDF5 file with pandas?

Tags: pandas, hdf5

I want to load some data in HDF5 format, some examples data file can be found in here:
https://gwosc.org/archive/links/O3GK_4KHZ_R1/G1/1270281618/1271462418/simple/

I **can** load the file with `h5py` or `PyTables` but **can't** manage to do it with pandas.

---

load the file with `h5py` or `PyTables` is fine:

```py
>>> import h5py
>>> dataFile = h5py.File(path_of_file)
>>> dataFile['strain/Strain'][...]
```

```py
>>> import tables
>>> file = tables.open_file(path_of_file, mode="r")
>>> file.root.strain.Strain.read()
```

I saw Pandas also have [HDF5 support](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#hdf5-pytables), I tried different ways, but **didn't** manage to do it.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_hdf(path_of_file)

ValueError: Dataset(s) incompatible with Pandas data types, not table, or no datasets found in HDF5 file.
```

```py
>>> pd.read_hdf(path_of_file, key="strain/Strain")

TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed
```

```py
>>> file = pd.HDFStore(path_of_file, 'r')
>>> file.keys()
```

This can be run without error, but the keys returned is empty.

So how can read HDF5 file with pandas? Is there any limitations on the HDF5 support of pandas?

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641246/pandas-cant-read-hdf5-file-created-with-h5py/33644128#33644128) claimed that "pandas interaction with HDF files is limited to specific structures that pandas understands". But this is about 8 years ago,and I can't find any information on the official documents.

Comment: My guess, but it's just that, a guess, is that the data is just not compatible with Pandas Dataframes. The one you mentioned (`strain`) seems to be a 1D array, so maybe it cannot read that type of data (which seems likely looking at the docs, but I am not sure)

Comment: That's also the answer of  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641246/pandas-cant-read-hdf5-file-created-with-h5py/33644128#33644128), but that was about 8 years ago, so I wander any thing has changed since then? Also I can't find any related warning in the official documents.

Comment: You're asking 2 questions in one: Question (A): How do you - generally - read a HDF5 file? Your call `pd.read_hdf(path_of_file)` looks good. Try to test it yourself by creating a dummy dataframe, then first write to HDF5, and then read your self-created file to test your code. Question (B): Is the specific file that you are trying to read valid? It looks like pandas can't interpret it, e.g., because the file is corrupt, data is not actually tabular, etc...

Comment: Pandas HDF5 support is better described as "pandas support for HDF files is limited to **PANDAS** specific data structures". Pandas uses a very specific data structure to create HDF files, and expects that same structure when it reads them. As a result, pandas can only read HDF files it created (and those that mimic that structure).

Comment: Partial support is not really support, I think it should make clear in official documents. I mean I have a HDF5 file with some part is tabular data, and want process it with pandas, and after various try, only find out I can't read it with pandas, that would be really a pain in the ass, and doesn't make sense to me. @kcw78 can you provide any link of the information source for your claim?

Comment: HDF5 is a container, not a format. The application that creates the file defines the data structure (schema). The reader then has to read based on that schema.  So, pandas HDF support is an _application specific HDF5 implementation_. In other words, pandas can read files it creates, and others that follow that schema. But it can't read files that don't follow the pandas schema. I will expand on this in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Questions about using pandas with HDF5 files comes up from time-to-time. I have answered a few questions about *creating* HDF5 files with pandas. Links to those answers are provided below:

1. [Pandas to HDF5?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74208251/10462884)
2. [Save data to hdf5 (e.g. from pandas df) with structure copied from
   another hdf5-file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74241371/10462884)

The 1st answer shows how to create 3 HDF5 files with pandas with different output parameters. If you run them, you will see each file has a pandas specific schema required for pandas to read them. (Each combination has a slightly different schema.) Use the **HDFView** utility from **The HDF Group** to view them. That is why I say "pandas HDF5 support is an application specific HDF5 implementation". It is not designed for general purpose access to any HDF5 file.

Background: HDF5 is a container, not a format. The user defines the schema to create the best data structure for their application. Programs that read the file have to follow that schema.

You need to use a general purpose HDF5 package to read the file if the file schema is not pandas compatible. As you disvered there are 2 good choices: pytables and h5py. I use both, and like each for different reasons. I suggest pytables if you want to read the data into pandas dataframes. pytables is the HDF5 package used by pandas so that reduces HDF5 compatibility issues.

You will also need to understand the schema. Ideally it is provided to you. If not, you can use HDFView to view it, or write code to interrogate for group and dataset names and attributes.

Code might look like this:

```
import tables as tb
with tb.File(path_of_file, mode="r") as h5f:
    strain_array = h5f.root.strain.Strain.read()
    # OR
    strain_array = h5f.get_node('/strain/Strain').read()
    # OR
    strain_dataset = h5f.get_node('/strain/Strain')
    strain_array = strain_dataset.read()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detail explanation, really appreciate your help. But my concerns still not quite clear:
1. Is there any **official** source on the limitations of pandas' HDF5 support. Those claims have been around for many years, but I can't find it anywhere except stackoverflow. Is this consider a feature or bug?

Comment: 2. The limitation also not make sense to me. I mean maybe the HDF5 file as a whole is not fully compatible with pandas, but I know there is a tabular data in the container of HDF5, which is compatible with pandas, and pyTables can get it out from the container. Then why can't pandas just read out the tabular data, which can be handle by pyTables under the hood. Isn't that `pd.read_hdf` means to do?

Comment: 1. The official pandas docs describe the HDF methods (`HDFStore`, `to_hdf` and `read_hdf`). `read_hdf` alludes to the limitation. It says: '_Retrieve **pandas object** stored in file ..._' (emphasis mine). IMHO, HDF is just another pandas output format; like CSV, JSON, HTML and XML files (and many others). Every `.to_XXX()` method has a matching `.read_XXX()` to _**read the file pandas created**_. Each follows a pandas specific schema that isn't documented. To read these files with another program you need the schema. The only way I know to get it is creating a test file.

Comment: 2. To read a HDF file you need an API and **the file schema**. So, yes, pandas reads a HDF file using PyTables as the API following a fixed pandas schema. You can use  `pd.read_hdf` if your file uses that schema. Otherwise, you have to use a general purpose HDF API. Now, all is not lost. You can read the GWOSC file with PyTables and load the data into pandas dataframes. If you want to save the dataframes to HDF, I recommend using a 2nd HDF file.

Comment: by `file schema` you means a tabular data is not enough, all meta info should also exist? 

p.s. `alludes to the limitation`: I think those limitation should made explicitly clear in the document, otherwise, it would be really confusion for noobs, and that's also why `Questions about using pandas with HDF5 files comes up from time-to-time.` I also asked on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/56560), hope they could give some response.

Comment: Most HDF5 files have more than 1 table of data (called a dataset). By schema, I mean the organization of the data into multiple datasets and groups. Metadata (attributes) are also important. In addition datasets can be homogeneous or heterogenous (defined like a numpy dtype). Look at the files created by my linked example, and you will see the different ways pandas organizes the data. They are the required data structures to be a "pandas object", and are different from the GWOSC file structure. That's why you can't use pandas to read your file.